# Why don't all Set-Cookie headers appear in the Cookies tab in DevTools?

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers, google-chrome-devtools

I'm logging in to my Identity Server .NET Core app running locally.

I can see there is a `Callback` redirect, and the response contains 5 `Set-Cookie` headers:

[image]

However, when I look in the Cookies tab, it only shows two response cookies:

- `idsrv.session`
- `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application`

[image]

The other three are not displayed:

- `idsrv.external`
- `idsrv.externalC1`
- `idsrv.externalC2`

Those three are, however, displayed in the request cookies, and they match with the `Cookie` request header.

**Why are only two of the five response cookies displayed in the Cookies tab?**

**Why is the expiry for the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` cookie set to 1970-01-01 but the `Set-Cookie` header for `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` has no expires attribute?**

Comment: @TZHX but how did `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` get 1970 as the expiry if there is no expires attribute in the `Set-Cookie` header?

Comment: I'm not sure, possibly a future request altered it? it seems to be in the middle of some oidc workflow of redirects

Answer (score 0):

Cookies with an expiration date in the past (like 1970...) are a request to the browser to remove the cookie from the browser cookie jar.

By the way, I blogged about solving common cookie problems [here](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/).